# Tier Price in configurable product

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, tierprice, tiered-pricing

I have created a configurable product with two configurations. In each configuration, I have added Quantity and Tier price.

Although the tier price does work, it does not show the tier price block on the storefront. Can anyone tell me,how to enable it?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are pictures from the product and one configuration.

Pic 1: https://ibb.co/eVt8M5)
Pic 2:(https://ibb.co/iN8KTk)
Pic 3:(https://ibb.co/dNz4uQ)

Comment: Can you please show us a screenshot of your configurable product details.

Comment: I 've added some pics

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using? It may only work with Magento >= 2.2. Additionally, mind that the tier price may only be shown after you select a specific product option in the frontend.